# Scala - How to group a 3 tuples List[(String, String, Int)] into List[List[(String, String, Int)]]

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

How do I split a 3-tuple List as mentioned into a List of List where elements with the same initial string are grouped together.

Ex -:

```
scala> List((abc,b,1),(b,c,2),(abc,m,3),(b,d,3),(c,c,3)) => 
List(List((abc,b,1),(abc,m,3)),List((b,c,2),(b,d,3)),List(c,c,3))
```

How can I implement this nicely in Scala?

Best Regards

Comment: Might want to add some comments about what you've tried and how it didn't work.

Comment: Try using `groupBy`.

Comment: I am relatively new to scala and from my understanding I would need something in the lines of a groupby or partition function. However, I am having trouble with the exact syntax

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet can you please elaborate on that a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupBy` which will get you a map of `String -> List` and then call `values` on the map to get just the lists:

```
list.groupBy(_._1).values.toList
```

Comment: Easy to understand and intuitive. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user133442 Note that you may not actually need `toList` depending on what you want to do with it.